# Appropriate statistical methods to analyze impact of specific intervention between treatment and control group

Tags: multivariate-analysis, likert

I am conducting a quasi-experiment design in which I have 72 students belonging to treatment group and 72 belonging to control group. The entry level of both groups are similar in terms of their performance in the qualifying university examination and a pretest conducted on them at the time of their entry into the course. I have these scores recorded as percentages.

Both groups underwent 2 months of training in the Academy and four months on-the-job-training.  The delivery method of training for the treatment group was different from that of the control group, though the content and objectives of training for both the groups were the same.
The outcome of each of the group was measured in terms of their accomplishment in technical and behavioral aspects. I have aggregated these scores from their sub-components and represented as percentages.

- I have also recorded sub-component scores of technical and behavioral components e.g. technical - ability to use different features of software, productivity, quality in terms of errors committed etc. and behavioral such as taking ownership, meeting deadlines, team work etc.
- The scores were obtained through a performance test (technical) followed by appraisal of project manager through structured feedback on two occasions (while undergoing on-the-job-training and confirmation appraisal after their training.
- The students also provided feedback on training in terms of - content, design, quality of instructions, training delivery etc.
- The feedback scores by project manager and participants were on Likert five-point scale which I have converted to percentages (I don't know if it's appropriate).

What statistical methods would be appropriate to study the impact of intervention on the outcome - technical and behavioral?